# How do i make my game link back to the start once user has made the wrong choice

Tags: python

im currently creating a text based adventure game, and i need to get the game to go back to the beginning once the user has died or chosen the wrong answer. i need it to ask the user if they wish to play again and then loop back to the beginning of the game.
anyone know how to do this, the help would be greatly appreciated.

this is the code -

```
#Python Text Adventure Game
#Created By Callum Fawcett
#Created On 20/07/19
#Version 0.1


# Setup
yes_no = ["yes", "no"]
directions = ["left", "right", "forward", "backward"]

# Introduction
name = input("What is your name, adventurer?\n")
print("Greetings, " + name + ". Let us go on a quest!")
print("You find yourself on the edge of a dark Jungle.")
print("Can you find your way through? and find the Hidden treasure at the end?\n")

# Start of game
response = ""
while response not in yes_no:
    response = input("Would you like to step into the Jungle?\nyes/no\n")
    if response == "yes":
        print("You head into the Jungle. You hear crows cawwing in the distance.\n")
    elif response == "no":
        print("You are not ready for this quest. Goodbye, " + name + ".")
        quit()
    else: 
        print("I didn't understand that.\n")

# Second part of game
response = ""
while response not in directions:
    print("To your left, you see a Tiger.")
    print("To your right, there is more Jungle.")
    print("There is a rock wall directly in front of you.")
    print("Behind you is the Jungle exit.\n")
    response = input("What direction do you move?\nleft/right/forward/backward\n")
    if response == "left":
        print("The Tiger eats you. Farewell, " + name + ".")
        quit()
    elif response == "right":
        print("You head deeper into the Jungle.\n")
    elif response == "forward":
        print("You cannot scale the wall.\n")
        response = "" 
    elif response == "backward":
        print("You leave the Jungle. Goodbye, " + name + ".")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I didn't understand that.\n")

# Third Part of game
response = ""
while response not in directions:
    print("To your left, there is a waterfall.")
    print("To your right, you see a run down house.")
    print("Directly in front of you is a dark staircase.")
    print("Behind you is the exit.\n")
    response = input("What direction do you wish to take?\nleft/right/forward/backward\n")
    if response == "left":
        print("You look off the edge of the waterfall, taking the time to think about your choices.\n")
        response = ""
    elif response == "right":
        print("The house is a trap, the doors and windows all shut behind you and youre trapped, Farewell, " + name + ".")
        quit()
    elif response == "forward":
        print("You head down the strairs\n")
    elif response == "backward":
        print("You leave the Jungle. Goodbye, " + name + ".")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I didn't understand that.\n")

# Fourth part of game
response = ""
while response not in directions:
    print("You're now at the bottom of the staircase, it has a come to a fork")
    print("To the right is a well lit path with a sign that reads 'Death to all who continue'.")
    print("To the left is a dark and gloomy path with a sign that reads 'free passage to all those who continue'. ")
    print("Directly in front of you is a a 50ft drop.")
    print("Behind you is the exit.\n")
    response = input("What direction do you wish to take?\nleft/right/forward/backward\n")
    if response == "left":
        print("You are attacked by forrst deamons. Goodebye," + name + ".")
        quit()
    elif response == "right":
        print("You continue through the forrest.\n")
    elif response == "forward":
        print("You cant go down there youll die.\n")
        response = ""
    elif response == "backward":
        print("You leave the Jungle. Goodebye" + name + ".")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I Didn't understand that.\n")

#Fifth part of game
response = ""
while response not in directions:
    print("You have continued through the dark forrest, and found yourself at a cross road.")
    print("To your left is a beaten path with a man lying on the ground.")
    print("To your right is a door.")
    print("Straight ahead is a dark path that is over grown and full of brambles and thorns.")
    print("behind you is the way you came and the way out.\n")
    response = input("What direction do you wish to take?\nleft/right/forward/backward\n")
    if response == "left":
        print("You walk to help the man, but it was a trap and you are attacked and killed by savages. Goodbye, " + name + ".\n")
        quit()
    elif response == "right":
        print("You go through the door, and it takes you to a mystical realm that you do not know, and now youre traped there. Goodbye, " + name + " Have fun.\n")
        quit()
    elif response == "forward":
        print("You continue through the dark Jungle, getting deeper and deeper. Lets hope you're not lost ;)\n")
    elif response == "backward":
        print("You Leave the Jungle. Goodbye" + name + ".")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I Didn't understand that")

#sixth part of the game.
response = ""
while response not in directions:
    print("You have made it through the thorns and brambles, and have come to a T in the path.")
    print("To your left is a bridge that doesnt look very stable and could break with the slightest bit of weight on it.")
    print("To your right is a dark path with a metal bridge that looks sturdy and safe.")
    print("Directly in front of you is a wall.")
    print("Behind you is the way you came and the way out.\n")
    response = input("What direction do you wish to take?\nleft/right/forward/backward\n")
    if response == "left":
        print("The bridge was actually very safe and you make your way over it, and continue on your quest\n")
    elif response == "right":
        print("The bridge wasnt stable and you have fallen to your death. Goodbye" + name + ".\n")
        quit()
    elif response == "forward":
        print("You cannot scale the wall\n")
        response = ""
    elif response == "backward":
        print("You leave the Jungle. Goodbye" + name + ".")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I Didn't Understand That")

#Final Part of The Game
response = ""
while response not in directions:
    print("You have come to the jungle temple, you make your way in through the door. Once inside you see three doors.")
    print("The door on the left has a weird symbol above it, and what looks like blood coming out from under the door.")
    print("The door on the right has no symbol above it, but does have two large lion statues by the door.")
    print("The door straight in front of you has a crown symbol above it, but has two skelitons sat outside it.")
    print("behind you is the way you came in and the way out.\n")
    response = input("What direction do you wish to take?\nleft/right/forward/backward\n")
    if response == "left":
        print("You open the door and something drags you inside, for you to never be seen again. Goodbye" + name + ".\n")
        quit()
    elif response == "right":
        print("You open the door and go inside, only to find 10 large lions who have not been fed in a very long time, they eat you. Goodbye" + name + ".\n")
        quit()
    elif response == "forward":
        print("You open the door and walk down the strairs infront of you, as you get lower and lower you start to see all the gold and treasure that has been left.")
        print("CONGRATULATIONS " + name + ", you found the Hidden jungle treasure, along with an exit back to the world.")
    elif response == "backward":
        print("You leave the temple and there are re risen soldiers ready to kill you. you die, Goodbye " + name + ".\n")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I Didn't understant that")
```

Comment: put all in `while` loop

Comment: @furas where would i put the while loop tho?

Comment: put all your code inside new `while` loop - and it will repeat all your code again and again.

Comment: ive edited the question as what i asked was slightly off from what i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution: move all of your current code to a function, let's call it "gameplay", 
and encapsulate it in a loop in the main function

```
def gameplay():

    # Setup
    yes_no = ["yes", "no"]
    ....
    ....
    ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        response = input("start a new game?y/n")
        if response != "y":
            break    
        print("Starting a new game")
        gameplay()
```

Comment: ive added this to my code, but when i choose the wrong answer in the first set it just ends the game

Comment: ive edited the question as what i asked was slightly off from what i wanted

Comment: this works great, is there a way of making it an option to start a new game rather than just starting one anyway

Answer (score 1):

put all your code inside a while loop and put `continue` to jump to the beginning of the loop

```
while True:
   ...
   ...
   if response == "some wrong answer": continue
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: tried this, but when it comes to the wrong answer i still need it to print out a message and i get an indent error

Comment: ive edited the question as what i asked was slightly off from what i wanted

Comment: if you mixed spaces and tabs you probably get an indent error sometimes, remove all white space and change them 4 spaces(or 2) or a tab for indentation